# Using different java based spring context configurations with cucumber

Tags: java, spring, cucumber, bdd

I am trying to get Cucumber working with Spring. In our code, we are already using java based Spring configuration. I am having trouble getting it to work in the following scenario. Can someone please help?

Today , in our integration test classes we use @ContextConfiguration for each class and provide the config class that is declared with in that integration test class for loading the beans. Config class is annotated with @Configuration. Same bean could be instantiated differently in 2 different classes Config classes used in 2 different integration test classes.

So when I use Cucumber, since the Contextconfiguration differs on different classes, it looks for 'Cucumber.xml' . In the xml file, I am using component-scan to scan the cucumber step definition classes by giving the package name that these classes use (both classes have same package name) . Since all beans gets loaded in same context, Cucumber is failing to load the beans when it finds the same bean defined in these different config classes .

How do I get over this problem of creating same bean but in different ways and use them in different classes?
Please note that I am not looking for a solution that creates lot of churn from our existing coding practices, so having per-test-xml file is not an option for me.

Here is how our code looks:

**Class NameAndAddressProviderIntegrationTestSteps :-**

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations="classpath:cucumber.xml")
public class NameAndAddressProviderIntegrationTestSteps {
@Configuration
@Import({
    xyz.class,
    abc.class,
    NameAndAddressProvider.class
})
@ImportResource({
        "file:configuration/spring-configuration/abc.xml",
        "file:configuration/spring-configuration/xyz.xml"
})
public static class Config {

    @Bean
    AccountHolderDataMap dataMap() {
        AccountHolderDataMap data = new AccountHolderDataMap();
        data.put(ID,
                new AccountHolderData(customerID));
       data.get(customerID).setCustomerplaceID(testCustomerplaceID);
        return data;
    }

 }
@Inject
private NameAndAddressProvider provider;

@When("^I call nameandAddress provider with a 'customerId'$")
public void i_call_nameandAddress_provider_with_a_customerId() throws DependencyException {
    System.out.println("Entering when method");
    names = provider.getNames(customerID);
    System.out.println(provider.toString());       
}
......
}
```

**Class AddressProviderIntegrationTestSteps:-**

```
 @ContextConfiguration(locations="classpath:cucumber.xml")
 public class AddressProviderIntegrationTestSteps {
 @Configuration
 @Import({
        abc.class,
        xyz.class,
        AddressesProvider.class
})
@ImportResource({
        "file:configuration/spring-configuration/test-environment.xml",
        "file:configuration/spring-configuration/test-logging-config.xml"
})
public static class Config {
    @Bean
    @DependsOn("Environment")
    AccountHolderDataMap data() {
        AccountHolderDataMap data = new AccountHolderDataMap();
       data.put(testCustomerID,
                new AccountHolderData(testCustomerID, testCustomerplaceID,businessType));
        return data;
    }
}

private static final String testCustomerID = "1234";
private static final String testMarketplaceID = "abc";

@Inject
private AddressesProvider provider;

@When("^I call AddressesProvider provider with a 'CustomerID'$")
public void i_call_AddressesProvider_provider_with_a_CustomerID() throws Throwable {
    List<Address> addresses = provider.getAddresses(testCustomerID);
    Log.info(addresses.get(0).toString());
    assertTrue(addresses.size()==1);
  }
```

}

And here is the nested exception I am getting:-
"nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [....AccountHolderDataMap] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: dataMap,data"

Appreciate your help!

Comment: maybe this answer can help a little http://stackoverflow.com/a/42366378/307699

Answer (score 1):

I've managed multiple sources for bean-definitions. You can use this at a starting point (or others in the internet as your question is quite old) 
I am using spring4, see my other cucumer post for the pom

At the stepdefs use a config.class

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { CucumberConfiguration.class })
public class StepdefsTest123 { 

    @Autowired bean; // from cucumberBeanContext.xml


    @When("^A$")
    public void a() throws Throwable {
        System.out.println(bean.getFoo());
    }

}
```

in the config-class add aditional beandefinitions

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages   = "package.here.cucumber")
@ImportResource("classpath:cucumberBeanContext.xml")
public class CucumberConfiguration {

    // nothing to do here

}
```