# Is it possible to configure cucumber to run the same test with different spring profiles?

Tags: java, spring, testing, cucumber, spring-profiles

I have an application where I'm running a trial with different technologies. I have a set of interfaces implemented with each technology and I use spring profiles to decide which technology to run. Each of the technologies has its own Spring java config annotated with the profile they are active for.

I run my cucumber tests defining which profile is the active one but this forces me to manually change the string every time I want to test a different profile, making it impossible to run automated tests for all of them. Is there anyway in cucumber to provide a set of profiles so tests are run once for each of them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two possibilities

1. Standard - use few test classes ran by Cucumber runners
2. Write custom Cucumber jUnit runner (or take ready one) that supports multiple configurations.

**In the first case**, it will look like below. The disadvantage is that you have to define different reports for each runner and have almost identical Cucumber runners for each config.

[image]

Here's how classes can look like:

`CucumberRunner1.java`

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(glue = {"com.abc.def", "com.abc.common"},
        features = {"classpath:com/abc/def/",
                "classpath:com/abc/common.feature"},
        format = {"json:target/cucumber/cucumber-report-1.json"},
        tags = {"~@ignore"},
        monochrome = true)
public class CucumberRunner1 {
}
```

`StepAndConfig1.java`

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:/com/abc/def/configuration1.xml"})
public class StepsAndConfig1 {
    @Then("^some useful step$")
    public void someStep(){
        int a = 0;
    }
}
```

`CucumberRunner2.java`

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(glue = {"com.abc.ghi", "com.abc.common"},
        features = {"classpath:com/abc/ghi/",
                "classpath:com/abc/common.feature"},
        format = {"json:target/cucumber/cucumber-report-2.json"},
        tags = {"~@ignore"},
        monochrome = true)
public class CucumberRunner2 {
}
```

`OnlyConfig2.java`

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = JavaConfig2.class)
public class OnlyConfig2 {
    @Before
    public void justForCucumberToPickupThisClass(){}
}
```

**The second approach** is to use custom cucumber runner that supports multiple configurations. You can either write it by yourself or take ready one, for example, mine - [CucumberJar.java](https://github.com/nahabi4/supplements/blob/master/cucumber-junit/src/main/java/nahabi4/supplement/cucumber/api/junit/CucumberJar.java) and root of project [cucumber-junit](https://github.com/nahabi4/supplements/blob/master/cucumber-junit/).
In this case Cucumber runner will looks like this:

`CucumberJarRunner.java`

```
@RunWith(CucumberJar.class)
@CucumberOptions(glue = {"com.abc.common"},
        tags = {"~@ignore"},
        plugin = {"json:target/cucumber/cucumber-report-common.json"})
@CucumberGroupsOptions({
        @CucumberOptions(glue = {"com.abc.def"},
                features = {"classpath:com/abc/def/",
                        "classpath:com/abc/common.feature"}
        ),
        @CucumberOptions(glue = {"com.abc.ghi"},
                features = {"classpath:com/abc/ghi/",
                        "classpath:com/abc/common.feature"}
        )
})
public class CucumberJarRunner {
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for that! It's kind of late for me to implement this now as the post is exactly one year old but I'll keep this in mind next time I have to do something similar :D

Comment: mm, for some reason I thought that this is this year question:)